# jQuery - datepicker

Tags: jquery

I know there were tones of questions like this - but I can't get this working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#input-datepicker").datepicker();
        });
</script>
```

Displays an error that there's no datepicker() function.

I tried so many script including combinations, none works. This is the current one:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

I tried adding `type="text/javascript"`, placing includes above/below the form, changing `$("#input-datepicker")` into div containing the field...nothing.

Can you help me?

EDIT.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#bbb").datepicker();
    });
</script>
<div id="input-datepicker" class="input">
    <label  for="bbb">Calendar</label>    <input name="bbb" id="bbb" type="text" />
</div>
```

EDIT 2.

```
<link type="text/css" href="..." rel="stylesheet" /> 
<form action="..." method="post" id="form" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">    <div id="input-file" class="input">
    <label for="aaa"></label>    <input  type="file" name="aaa" id="aaa"  </div><script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#bbb").datepicker();
    });
</script>
<div id="input-datepicker" class="input">
    <label  for="bbb">Calendar</label>    <input name="bbb" id="bbb" type="text" />
</div>
<div id="input-submit" class="input">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
// ...
</form>
```

Comment: How doesn't it work? Do you get any errors?

Comment: TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

Comment: Syntax seems fine, what does your HTML look like?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsbin.com/igivum/1/edit

Comment: Where is this code in relation to your jQuery and jQuery UI script tags?

Comment: It's an included file, it doesn't have any HTML/BODY tags - so the code is right above the form's field.

Comment: @user2124857: Do you have jQuery/jQuery UI added *before* the `$("#input-datepicker").datepicker();` code?

Comment: Yes, I do. The field is inside of a div tag, if this matters.

Comment: @user2124857: Do you get any errors in your JS console?

Comment: TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function 

$("#bbb").datepicker();

Comment: Your code works for me as-is: http://jsbin.com/igivum/3/edit

Comment: @user2124857: Can you copy the *entire* HTML source and edit it into the question?

Comment: Ok, this is the whole source. Just //... is a couple of jquery lines (validation plugin).

Comment: In your newest update, you show that you are loading jQuery *after* jQuery UI.  This **won't work**.  I ***highly*** suggest putting all your `<link>` and `<script>` tags in your `<head>`, and not scattered throughout the page like that.

Comment: Yes, indeed, putting everything into the head section solved the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check that your input field id matches the id in the jquery selector you are using (input-datepicker).

The jquery example is here: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/